# cannot find derive macro `Selectable` in this scope

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

when I added the `Selectable` in rust diesel `diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }` code like this:

```
#[derive(Insertable,Queryable,QueryableByName,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Clone,Selectable)]
#[table_name = "bill_record"]
pub struct BillRecord {
    pub id: i64,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub deleted: i32,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub bill_book_id: i64,
    pub remark: Option<String>,
    pub amount: i64,
    pub bill_book_contents_id: i64,
    pub account_id: i32,
}
```

the compiler shows error `cannot find derive macro Selectable in this scope`. I have tried to add the micro driver like this in `main.rs`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel_drivers;
```

could not fixed this error, I also read the diesel source code and found the Selectable come from diesel_drivers. why could not fixed this problem even add the drivers macro? what should I do to fix it? I also tried to add `use diesel::*;` in the model, still not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try rectifying the typo - it is "derives" instead of "drivers"

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel_derives;
```

https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel_derives/derive.Selectable.html

Comment: Can't find crate for `diesel_derives` when I added the macro. @cargo_run

Comment: @Dolphin Did you add the dependency to cargo.toml file? You will have to add
diesel_derives = "1.4.1"

Comment: I add the dependencies `diesel_derives = "1.4.1"` and add macro success, but still could not find Selectable. @cargo_run

Comment: Are you using rustc to build code by any chance?

Comment: It seems works when i using the newest version of diesel_derives 2.0.0-rc.0 @cargo_run

Comment: seems the diesel and diesel derives have some imcompatible problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72674736/how-to-handle-the-compatible-problem-with-diesel-and-diesel-derives should I use the diesel derives independently? @cargo_run

Comment: Yes. Check the crate documentation for dependency mapping: https://crates.io/crates/diesel/1.4.8/dependencies

Comment: could you help me with the diesel group by clause, I could not figure out where is going wrong. https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/discussions/3209 @cargo_run